How should we tag questions about "The Penguin" TV series and other shows set in "The Batman" universe?
The 2024 TV series The Penguin is a spin-off of the 2022 film The Batman, set in the same universe and taking place shortly after the events of the movie. A sequel to The Batman is also in the works.
A recent question about The Penguin was initially tagged with the-batman-2022, but this tag was later removed by another user. Should we create a universe tag for The Batman and The Penguin, along with their sequels and spin-offs?
This approach would be similar to the marvel-cinematic-universe tag, which covers all shows in that franchise. (Related meta post: What to do with the [marvel-cinematic-universe]?) Alternatively, we could follow the example of the john-wick tag, which serves a dual purpose by referring to both the first John Wick movie and the series as a whole. (Related meta post: Should there be tag for the [John-Wick-series])
Having a dedicated universe tag could help populate the "Related Questions" list with more relevant content. It would also allow users interested in this particular Batman universe to easily follow and find questions about the film, its spin-offs, and any future sequels. What are your thoughts on this tagging approach?

I didn't downvote it but it's too early to create a franchise tag. It's just one movie and a show and seeing DC history it can get cancelled anyway. I do support franchise tags but overuse will be messy.

@AnkitSharma Can you write that as an answer so that I can accept it?

As Ankit Sharma mentioned in a comment,

it's too early to create a franchise tag. It's just one movie and a show and seeing DC history it can get cancelled anyway. I do support franchise tags but overuse will be messy.

